# Problem changing to Production mode - Command returned non-zero exit code

Tags: magento2

My Magento 2 was running normally, then I tried to change for production mode and I'm getting the following error:

```
Command returned non-zero exit code: 
`php -f /var/www/magento2.strip-curtains.com/public_html/bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant 2>&1`
```

When I run the command #php -f /var/www/magento2.strip-curtains.com/public_html/bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant 2>&1

```
[ReflectionException] Class \Smartwave\Megamenu\Model\Attribute\SubcatColumns does not exist
setup:di:compile-multi-tenant [--serializer="..."] [--extra-classes-file="..."] [--generation="..."] [--di="..."] [--exclude-pattern="..."] [--magento-init-params="..."]
```

I can only run the site if I set back to developer mode.

Comment: Same problem here. Seems to be a problem with a theme. Same output when I run the command manually: [ReflectionException] Class \Smartwave\Megamenu\Model\Attribute\SubcatColumns does not exist Smartwave is the vendor of a theme called "porto" which is quite popular. I will ask them and come back with their answer. Perhaps somebody already solved the problem here and can also help?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think you are running into one of three issues.

1. You need to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` to update the list of modules in case you have removed or changed one. If you did remove the `Smartwave` module without resetting your `app/etc/config.php` it's possible to get this error.
2. You have removed the `Smartwave` module but there is still code the uses some of it's classes or extends from it that haven't been updated.
3. You need to clear that var folder's that could have old content in them. They are typically `var/di, var/view_preprocessed, var/cache, var/page_cache, var/generation`. Clearing these might solve the issue.

From here, I would grep for the use of the `Smartwave` module in the `app` and `vendor` folders and see what comes up to figure out where it's being used.

`grep -r "Smartwave" app/*`

Comment: I am confused about "Smartwave" and have same problem like. My issue: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/161645/29175

Comment: When you run the search, does anything come up?

Comment: I am aware about all steps mentioned in answer but wanna know about Smartwave

Comment: oh, i have no idea what it is. looks to be a mega menu, but i'm only using that as it's in the error message in the orig post.